# How can I check if outgoing rsync traffic is actually encrypted

Tags: ssh, rsync, encryption

I have setup an automated `rsync` script between two servers using SSH keys. The script runs fine but I'd like to check if the traffic sent by `rsync` is actually going via encrypted SSH. How can I check this?

`rsync` does not report whether the data is actually using SSH, so I would like to check the data flow somehow.

I am using :

```
rsync -azvPh --progress --stats /mydata mydomain.server.org:/backup_folder
```

Answer (score 2):

`ssh` is always encrypted. Increase verbosity with muliple `-v`-flags to check on the commands `rsync` initiates:

```
rsync -vv fileA userA@server1.com:~/

opening connection using: ssh -l userA server1.com rsync --server -vve.LsfxCIvu . "~/"  (10 args)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
delta-transmission enabled                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
total: matches=1  hash_hits=1  false_alarms=0 data=0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
sent 80 bytes  received 72 bytes  304.00 bytes/sec                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
total size is 2  speedup is 0.01
```

First line indicates `ssh` connection being initiated.

Of course this does not verify the data stream itself, if your question was focussing on that.

Comment: thanks - yes, everyone says "rsync uses SSH and is therefore encrypted" but I'd like to see it myself. There must be a way to proof that the network traffic (via the internet) is actually encrypted. I am thinking if the network stream includes some readable clear text then it is not encrypted, if it is just letter-salad, then it is obviously encrypted. How can I see the data stream that rsync is sending out?

Comment: @Marc yes. Use `tshark`, `tcpdump`, or the graphical Wireshark. You can also use the `-e` flag to specify the transport layer. This defaults to `ssh` on modern versions of `rsync` but you can override it if required

Comment: Great - tcpdump might be what I need - many thanks. Also I thought, if I can see on the destination side that rsync is connecting on port 22, then I am also assured that the traffic is encrypted. Is there a tool to see who is connected to a port and sending incoming traffic?

Comment: If you don’t trust that “rsync uses SSH” means that the traffic is encrypted, then you shouldn’t trust that a connection to port 22 means that it’s encrypted. Sniff the traffic, that way you’ll be sure.

Comment: To check that rsync is using the port 22 on the server you can use `ss -ant` to check if you can see an ESTAB connection from your client or the old `netstat -antp` to check ESTABLISHED connections

Comment: @Marc Well, not necessarely port 22 means SSH, it could be listening on another port, but in the context of the situation I guess that would be transparent.